# Error running react native project for iOS

Tags: android, ios, typescript, react-native

I am new to react native.
I am running a existing project of react native. I am having a hard time running it for iOS. Already cleaned build , clean pod cache , reinstall pod files.
Now every time i run sudo npm run ios i am getting the below errors.

```
TypeError: str.replace is not a function
    at inlineString (/Users/ealpha4tech/Downloads/EAlpha Code/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-tools/build/errors.js:25:33)
    at new CLIError (/Users/ealpha4tech/Downloads/EAlpha Code/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-tools/build/errors.js:13:11)
    at getProjectInfo (/Users/ealpha4tech/Downloads/EAlpha Code/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/tools/getProjectInfo.js:29:11)
    at Object.runIOS [as func] (/Users/ealpha4tech/Downloads/EAlpha Code/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/commands/runIOS/index.js:82:58)
    at Command.handleAction (/Users/ealpha4tech/Downloads/EAlpha Code/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:108:23)
    at Command.listener [as _actionHandler] (/Users/ealpha4tech/Downloads/EAlpha Code/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:482:17)
    at /Users/ealpha4tech/Downloads/EAlpha Code/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:1283:65
    at Command._chainOrCall (/Users/ealpha4tech/Downloads/EAlpha Code/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:1177:12)
    at Command._parseCommand (/Users/ealpha4tech/Downloads/EAlpha Code/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:1283:27)
    at /Users/ealpha4tech/Downloads/EAlpha Code/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:1081:27
```

All the errors coming from the node modules seems.
I am very confused what i am doing wrong in setup.
Please help